# fill an fixed array with values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and i'm learning by writing bits of code and see what will happen. This is what i did yesterday:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("size of array:");
    int size = sc.nextInt();

    String tab[] = new String[size];
    System.out.println(tab.length);
    System.out.println("type your words:");
    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        tab[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length;i++){
        System.out.println(tab[i] + " " +i);
    }
}
```

This is what i get as output:

```
size of array:
3
3
type your words:
a
b
0
a 1
b 2
```

My question is why i can only enter two values and they start from index 1?
I know I can use an ArrayList and everything works if dimension of array will be hardcoded. I'm not looking for working code, rather than explanation why is happening like that.
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sc.nextInt()` just reads the `int`-part of your input. The end-of-line character is not read. Which means that the first time you call `sc.nextLine()` that end-of-line character is read instead of the new input you want to give.

Add `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()` and your code should work as expected